# What is Dirac indices?

Tags: definition, notation, dirac-equation, spinors

In Maggiore A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory Eq. 4.31

$$\{\Psi_a(\vec x,t),\Psi_b(\vec x,t)\}=\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y))  
  \delta_{ab}$$

where "$a,b=1,2,3,4$ are the Dirac indices".

However, The definition of Dirac indices were nowhere to be find.
I knew that there were four independent basis for the field (for $s=1,2$), did they mean that? i.e. $a=1,2$ for $s=1$ and $a=3,4$ for $s=2$?

What's the Dirac indices?

Comment: What is $s$? ...

Comment: Dirac spinors have four components. The “Dirac indices” label them.

Comment: @G.Smith $s$ was $u^s(p),v^s(p)$, i.e. the pair of particle and anti particle solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $u$-spinor solutions $u_{a}(s,p)$, which you mention in the comments, the spinor index $a$ runs over $a = \{1,2,3,4\}$, whilst *independently* $s$ refers to the two different spin states. And we have the $v_{a}(s,p)$ for the negative energy solutions.

Take $\mathbf{p} = (0,0,p_z)$, then the positive energy spinor solutions for the different values of $s=1,2$ are
\begin{align}
u_{a}(1,p) = \begin{bmatrix}
           \sqrt{E+m} \\
           0 \\
           \sqrt{E-m} \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad 
u_{a}(2,p)  = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           \sqrt{E+m} \\
           0 \\
           -\sqrt{E+m}
         \end{bmatrix} \ .
\end{align}
The spinor index $a$ still runs over $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so for example $u_{1}(1,p)=\sqrt{E+m}$. As you probably know, when you write the fields $\Psi_a (\mathbf{x},t)$ explicitly we include the $u$- and $v$-spinor solutions, whilst summing over $s$, with the spinor index $a$ being free.

---

If you're asking more generally about the space of the Dirac/spinor indices, I think there's already questions on that here, e.g. [spinor vs vector indices of Dirac gamma matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389413/spinor-vs-vector-indices-of-dirac-gamma-matrices). There's also quite a lot of resources online about spinors generally, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3824

Comment: So, it's "Minkowski" vector indices instead of Dirac indices? Because change the representation to higher dimension space such as $8$ should not affect the solution, thus, the $a,b$ ranged through $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ while there's still $4$ independent number of vector $u^s$ and $v^s$?

Comment: @shoutOutandCalculate They're not 'Minkowski' because they don't refer to the spacetime indices. They refer to the internal spinor degrees of freedom. Does https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377515/how-are-the-spinor-indices-different-from-the-spacetime-or-lorentz-indices help?

Comment: Thank you. It's the vector indices of the Spinor space. (Just in case anyone had the same question: See Eletie's answer and Creo's answer in the link.)